# Android SDK for Windows 2000

Tags: android

Is any SDK version which support Windows 2000? r05 doesn't - I found that \android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe imports from WS2_32.dll functions freeaddrinfo, getaddrinfo and getnameinfo which missed from this library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you -can- install Eclipse 3.5, the Android SDK (tested on r07) -AND- use the emulator, even on win2k-pro, sp4. The emulator took about 2-min to load, for me.

win2k's WS2_32.DLL doesn't provide three functions that emulator.exe needs -BUT- don't try replacing the win2k DLL with one from an XP system or you may corrupt win2k.

Instead, make a copy of \WINNT\system32\WS2_32.DLL and paste it to your .\android-sdk-windows\tools  directory.

Next, in the \tools directory, rename the copy to WS2_32_ORG.DLL.
Finally, download this file to your .\android-sdk-windows\tools  directory.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/y93qnt29h3q77v7/ws2_32.dll

You can now use the emulator on win2k, either from Eclipse or from the command line.

The file you download is named WS2_32.DLL, but it's really a stub that provides only the missing functions, any other winsock calls are passed-through to WS2_32_ORG.DLL, which is the renamed copy of your system's valid winsock DLL.

Because these files are placed in the \tools directory, they are only visible to executables in that folder, all other apps on your system will continue to use the winsock DLL in your \system32 folder.

The stub DLL was written by Old_Cigarette to overcome similar problems with gaming apps on win2k. 
win2kgaming-dot-site90-dot-com (I can only post one hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your going to have to get a more modern windows machine to do android builds on or switch to linux or mac.